# Optimizing Morphological Operation in iOS OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, optimization, opencv3.0, image-morphology

I am using openCV framework for my iOS application. I am trying to look for an optimization in morphological operation which is taking 53% of the entire process. Following is the code for morphological operation:

```
// MARK: Closing the image (Method-1)
    cv:: Mat bw2;
    cv:: Mat erodedBW2;
    cv:: Mat se = getStructuringElement(0, cv::Size(140,140));
    cv::dilate(Bw_med, bw2, se);
    cv::erode(bw2, erodedBW2, se);

// MARK: Closing the image (Method-2)
    cv::morphologyEx(BW_med, erodedBW2, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, se);
```

As you see I am applying erosion followed by an dilation, which is equivalent of closing operation. I have tried the closing operation using MorphologyEx; but the performance is still the same (included in the code above) Is there a better optimization method?

Comment: An erosion followed by a dilation is an opening, not a closing, but it does not change your problem. Moreover, it's exactly the same to do erosion+dilation and opening, so same processing time. If you take a look to Marc Van Droogenbroeck library, he has a way to do opening/closing in only one operation, but borders processing are different. Moreover, his library is optimized for decomposable structuring element, and I think that it's not the case with OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

Your structuring element is **very** large: 140x140. Do you really need that much? Try starting at 5x5 and compare results slowly increasing it.

Comment: Yes. so far I have tried on various papers with text, I have found 140 to be the optimum. For almost a clean paper, 30 is enough; but I need to consider many different cases, where the lighting may not be uniform. Something I missed on the post is that the purpose of this morphological operation is to eliminate the non-uniform background, if it exists.

Comment: Next thing I'd try is reducing image resolution. AFAIK the opencv morpho operators are already nearly optimal (O(n * sqrt(k)), for n image pixels and k structural element pixels), there isn't really much room for improvement there, unless you tile the image and parallelize.